# Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS and MSI N3150I ECO fails to boot after install

Tags: boot, grub2, screen

After installing Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS on an MSI N3150I ECO motherboard with 64bit processor, 2TB drive, the system fails to boot. I have clear legible screen through the entire install process. The system shows the GRUB2 menu, but after choosing UBUNTU to boot, the screen displays a few system level text info pieces and then goes to a garbled white static screen.

At this point the keyboard is locked up. I have tried NumLock and CapsLock and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> to restart. None of those are functioning as expected for a non frozen system.

Other things tried:

- change the display to 1024x768. Same thing. garbled screen
- Put drive in a different system. Works fine. except for rename the network card in config. to be expected.
- Tried reinstall with force UEFI and also just using legacy boot. Both have the same issue. Garbled screen after grub menu is acknowledged.
- Tried reinstalling Intel HD graphics drivers on other system and then bringing back to the MSI motherboard system. No change.
- vbeinfo and vbetest seem to pass when in grub command line.

Anything else I should try?

Comment: Please try Ctrl+Alt+F1 and see if you can go to TTY1 (a command line environment)

Comment: The above notwithstanding, you should also update BIOS/UEFI (v2.1 mentions *Updated GOP and VBIOS* in the changelog) as it may make a difference.

Comment: Will try tonight and router back. I have updated BIOS already. Will check for any further updates.